# notify vs notifyAll in a Producer-Consumer application

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

The [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) contain a basic [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) for Producer-Consumer applications using guarded blocks. They also give a short explanation of the difference and typical use cases for notify vs notifyAll.

My question regarding the example code:

is it possible to change the code of the put and take methods

```
    //Notify producer that status has changed.
    notifyAll();
```

and

```
    //Notify consumer that status has changed.
    notifyAll();
```

to use notify() instead of notifyAll() and still have a correct implementation of the Producer-Consumer pattern?

Comment: In most cases yes, but it depends on what the consumers are supposed to do.

Comment: BTW: I wouldn't use the low level notify/notifyAll/wait unless you really have to.  I would use an ExecutorService and possibly a separate Queue.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be multiple consumers (or producers) it is necessary to notify all of them, otherwise only one consumer will wake up and consume, all others will sleep until the producer accidentially wakes them up.
In most cases I have seen notifyAll() is the better (i.e. maybe minimal less performance, but less problems) solution.

Comment: That is why I said that it depends on what the consumers are doing. It's quite common that you only want one consumer to consume the produced event. The rest will wait.